# Evolution Email Replies are not Properly Threaded for Recipients in Outlook/Exchange

Tags: email, evolution

I work in an almost 100% Windows Desktop (save for a handful of Macs and a few rebels running Linux). I've been using evolution-ews as my mail client. While it works great for me - I've been having some issues with email threading. The feature works perfectly for on my end, however my replies are not properly threaded for my co-workers using outlook/exchange. That is messages are still grouped together, however each of my replies look like they are a new top level thread within the same message group.

I there a setting I can make which changes my emails to a more outlook/exchange friendly format so threading works correctly?

Outlook:
[image]

Evolution:
[image]